# Indexing Sitecore Profile Cards and their value

Tags: c#, lucene, sitecore, sitecore8

I'm currently indexing the `Profile Cards` applied to an Item, in the `Tracking` field, via a custom `ComputedField`. This works great, I can retrieve results based on it matching Profile Cards I'm searching with.

However I want to take into account the `value` of the `Profile Card`. I.e. A result Item with a 10 in the Aviation `Profile Card` should be more relevant than another result with 5 in the Aviation `Profile Card`.

An obvious way to achieve this is via `Boosting`, but this would need to occur at `Indexing` time opposed to `Search` time.

Is there a way to apply boosting at Indexing time based on the values in a field? Or is there another way?

There is the option to sort the results by Profile Card value post-search but that isn't very performant and rather put that overhead at indexing time.

Comment: I was working on this the other day. I was trying to use Lucene Sub Documents, but I am not sure if that is going to work. Also looking into Coveo as a possible choice. I have not come up with a solution yet, but I am working on creating a new index that just indexes items, profile cards and values. I am going to push each profile and value into a single field as a delimited value. That way, I can take my results, extract profile values and calculate the ranking on the fly.

Comment: I think you are headed down the same path as I am. Just to help you, I wanted to reference my blog post where I made getting the profiles from the tracker performant. http://www.waitingimpatiently.com/parsing-the-__tracker-object-for-indexing/

Comment: I had considered using the profile id and value in a single field with a pipe separator, which your blog uses. How did you find that? Thanks for sharing the post, anything to help with performance :)

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this by creating a custom rule that boosts each indexed item based on the values of its profile card.

You can see examples of creating boosting rules below:

- http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/john-west-sitecore-blog/posts/2013/05/sitecore-7-boosting-items-by-depth-with-the-rules-engine.aspx
- https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/search_and_indexing/search_result_boosting#_Ref350961403

**EDIT:** Note that this approach will apply boosting for items in **all** search queries in all of your indexes. This will actually be true for all index-time approaches. So you might want to go with query-time boosting after all.

Comment: I had considered Rule-Based boosting but there wasn't many resources actually explaining how to construct the rule, other than creating the Rule Item. I can always decompile existing code to get an idea